# Problem with limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\lambda_{i}|^{n} n^{\ell}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How I can calculate next:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |\lambda_{i}|^{n} n^{\ell} ? 
$$
Where $|\lambda_{i}|<1$ and $\ell$ is any positive integer.

Comment: What is $\ell$? Also perhaps you mean $|\lambda_i| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} |\lambda_{i}|^{n} n^{\ell} = 
\left(\lim_{n\to \infty} |\lambda_{i}|^{n/\ell} n\right)^{\ell} = 
\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{n}{e^{-[\ln(|\lambda_{i}|)/\ell]n}}\right)^{\ell}
$$
From there, L'Hôpital's rule, perhaps, noting $\ln(|\lambda_i|) < 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm very thankful

Comment: @MEagle Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Now I try to use L'Hôpital's rule and I calculate derivates, then I get

$\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} ln^{l-1}}{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}-(\ln(|\lambda_{i}|)/l)e^{-(\ln(|\lambda_{i}|)/l)n}}$ and now I can use L'Hôpital's rule again and again??